# increase and decrease value using a radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing an eCommerce system.
Let say if user has total of 1200 right.
If he chooses fast delivery options
40 should be added to total that means at the end amount should be changed from 1200 to 1240. 
I have a developed a kind of application for that.
I don't know what but the value is not increment. Don't know what but I need a solution,
Here is my code:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="target">
<span class="label label-success">Fast Delivery</span></label>
<div id="output">10</div>
<div id="savevalue" style="visibility:hidden"></div>



<label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="target2">
<span class="label label-success">Regular Delivery</span></label>
```

My Javascript code:

```
$('#target').click(function() {

var savevalue = $('#savevalue').text();
var output = $('#output').text();

if (savevalue==null || savevalue=="")
{
   output = output*1 + 40;
   savevalue = output;
   $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return output}); 
   $('#savevalue').html(function(i, val) { return savevalue}); 

}
});

$('#target2').click(function() {
var savevalue = $('#savevalue').text();
var output = $('#output').text();

if (output==savevalue)
{
   output = output*1 - 40;
   $('#output').html(function(i, val) { return output });
 }   
});
```

Comment: I think you might have an error on line 1 `[My JS FIDDLE CODE][1]`

Comment: I missed code :P in hurry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

HTML :

```
<p id="price">100</p>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" id="delivery1" value="normal" checked> Normal <br>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" id="delivery2" value="fast"> Fast
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#delivery1,#delivery2').change(function(){
    price = $('#price').text();
    if($('#delivery2').is(':checked')) {
        price = parseInt(price) + 40;

    } else {
        price = parseInt(price) - 40;
    }
    $('#price').text(price);
  });
});
```

Comment: This will never hit the `else` because it's only firing when clicking the `target` element so it'll always be checked.

Comment: change 'click' event to 'change' event

Comment: Okay! so second radio button is not required I understood! But this code is not working ! cn you try it out on JSFiddle and share me a link for that?

Comment: @Rijin  I Think I might be having syntax error ! because its not even executing a if statement neither else so..

Comment: Stupdi question, do you even have jQuery loaded? and check the console for errors

Comment: I guess @Jeffrey, I am not that much stupid as you thought! i was trying my code in JSFiddle only. I already mentioned it in code...

Comment: @Rijin Umm best I was looking for! Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

can you check on my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3422ntLh/.

In my solution, check the html code.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="delivery" id="target" speed="fast">
    <span class="label label-success">Fast Delivery</span></label>
<div id="output">10</div>
<div id="original" value="10" style="visibility:hidden"></div>



<label>
    <input type="radio" name="delivery" id="target2" speed="normal">
    <span class="label label-success">Regular Delivery</span></label>
```

I saved the value of the good in $('#original).

This is my JS code:

```
$('input:radio[name="delivery"]').change(function() {
    alert($('#original').attr('value'));
    $('#output').html($('#original_cost').attr('value'));
    if ($(this).attr('speed') == 'fast') {
        var extra_shipping_fee = 40;
        var current_price = parseInt($('#original').attr('value'));
        var new_price = current_price + extra_shipping_fee;
        $('#output').html(new_price);
    } else {
        $('#output').html($('#original').attr('value'));
    }
})
```

The code is not refine, but it will give you some insights on how to continue